# How to creat records in odoo tree view onclick button?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

please help
I need when I click Enregistrer Button to create those fields in the tree view on the bottom

for this example, I have quantity equal 12 so I need 12 lines to be created on the tree view with the values on the wizard view

[image]

the wizard code :

```
class LinesWizard(models.Model):
    _name = 'bons.wizard'
    w_contrat_name = fields.Many2one('contrat.contrat', string='Contrat')
    w_contrat_line = fields.Many2one('contrat.lignes', string='Ligne contrat')
    w_product_name = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Produit')
    w_po_number = fields.Char(string='Numero PO')
    w_qtt = fields.Float('quantite', related='w_contrat_line.quantity')
    w_prix = fields.Float(string='Prix unitaire', related='w_contrat_line.unit_price')

    @api.onchange('w_contrat_name')
    def on_change_contrat_name(self):
        if self.w_contrat_name:
            self.w_contrat_line = False
            return {'domain': {'w_contrat_line' : [('ligne_ids', '=', self.w_contrat_name.id)]}}
        else:
            return {'domain': {'w_contrat_line': []}}
```

Comment: How did you open the wizard by a button. And why you are using a wizard for this.is it because you hate creating lines in the tree view. And is this view for a custom model or sale.order

Comment: To open the wizard I create a button on the header of **sale.order** , and why wizard, because is a request of the work they need to create a multi-tree line in one click, depends on the quantity And this view  **sale.order** @Cherif

Comment: Can you show a minimum code to reproduce this?

Comment: @WaKo done , I add the wizard code

Comment: You can add a button to fill the order lines from the wizard.Odoo already provided a good example at http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/howtos/backend.html#launching-wizards

Comment: thank you, but the wizard is already launched, for my case, I need when I click to the **enregistrer** (see the picture ) then a **X** number of records fill the order lines with data from the wizard @WaKo

Answer (score 0):

In your function for the Enregistrer button, you can use below code to get the active `sale.order` ID.

```
session_id = self.env['sale.order'].browse(self._context.get('active_id'))
```

Then in the same function, simply create and add your rows.

```
session_id.write({
    'your_tree_ids': [(0, False, 
        {
        'w_contrat_name': self.w_contrat_name,
        'w_product_name': self.w_product_name,
        'etc': 'etc...'}
        )] * int(self.w_qtt) # assuming rows to be added are the same, create a list of w_qtt quantity of (0, _, values), since your qty is a float, need to convert to int first
    })
```